# Request object null on post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a form set up in pug that looks like this:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 David A Hines
  h2 #{posts[0].title}
  p #{posts[0].body}
  div
   form(action='/insert_post',method='post')
    div(id='title_div',data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        p
          label(for='title') Title
        p
          input(id='title',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        p
          label(for='body') Body
        p
          textarea(id='body',cols="40", rows="5", type='textarea',value='',placeholder='')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='author_name') Author Name
        input(id='author_name',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
        label(for='author_email') Author Email
        input(id='author_email',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
       input(type='submit',value='Submit Post',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

It hits /insert_post where /insert post makes a record in the db but the request object is completely null.

Here is my insert_post action:

```
router.post('/insert_post', function(req, res, next) {
    var postsArray = [];
    MongoClient.connect(database.url, function(err, db) {
        var db = db.db(database.database);
        if (!err) {
            console.log("We are connected");
            var postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
            console.log("request: "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
            var postObject = {
              title: req.body.title,
              body: req.body.body,
              author: {
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email
              }
            }
            postsCollection.insertOne(postObject, function(err, response) {
                console.log("Inserted Post: "+JSON.stringify(response.ops[0]));
                res.render('index', {
                    posts: response.ops[0]
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error:" + err);
            res.end("error: " + err);
        }
    });
});
```

I know that request.body can be null if you don't have body-parser installed, which I have set up in my app.js so I'm really not sure what's going on here.

EDIT: It might make a difference that my package.json version for express says ~4.16.0 so if that means it's above or equal to 4.16 I shouldn't need to use bodyParser?

Comment: I think I really don't get what bodyParser is doing, to be honest. Is this decoding the data that gets sent through post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You need to pass name in the input fields & post data to express node js.

server-side Code:-

```
 router.post('/insert_post', function(req, res, next) {
        var postsArray = [];
        MongoClient.connect(database.url, function(err, db) {
            var db = db.db(database.database);
            if (!err) {
                console.log("We are connected");
                var postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
                console.log("request: "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
                var postObject = {
                  title: req.body.title,
                  body: req.body.body,
                  author: {
                    name: req.body.author_name,
                    email: req.body.author_email
                  }
                }
                postsCollection.insertOne(postObject, function(err, response) {
                    console.log("Inserted Post: "+JSON.stringify(response.ops[0]));
                    res.render('index', {
                        posts: response.ops[0]
                    });
                });
            } else {
                console.log("error:" + err);
                res.end("error: " + err);
            }
        });
    });
```

pug file code :-

```
 extends layout

    block content
      h1 David A Hines
      h2 #{posts[0].title}
      p #{posts[0].body}
      div
       form(action='/insert_post',method='post')
        div(id='title_div',data-role='fieldcontain')
          fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
            p
              label(for='title') Title
            p
              input(id='title',name='title',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
          fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
            p
              label(for='body') Body
            p
              textarea(id='body',name='body',cols="40", rows="5", type='textarea',value='',placeholder='')
          fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
            label(for='author_name') Author Name
            input(id='author_name',name='author_name',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
            label(for='author_email') Author Email
            input(id='author_email',name='author_email',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
        div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
           input(type='submit',value='Submit Post',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

Comment: Okay I see the name changes in the pug file, did you change anything in the server code?

Comment: Yes I changed server side name which passes from `req.body`.